# Como posso realizar a leitura de um arquivo txt em C, linha a linha?

Tags: c, string

sou iniciante em C, estou tentando realizar a leitura de um arquivo txt que possua mais de uma linha, porem quando utilizo o fgets ele só lê a primeira linha, como posso ler o arquivo inteiro?

o que eu já fiz até o momento

```
    void main()
{
  FILE *arq, *arq1;
  char Linha[50];
  char *result;
  int i;
  char string[50];

    //printf("digite uma das opcoes\n");
    //printf("(1) Converter texto para maiusculo\n");
   // printf("(2) Converter texto para minusculo\n");
   // printf("(3) Primeira letra em maiusculo\n");
    //printf("(4) inverter texto\n");





  arq = fopen("string.txt", "rt");
  if (arq == NULL)  // Se houve erro na abertura
  {
     printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo\n");
     return;
  }
  i = 1;
  while (!feof(arq))
  {

      result = fgets(Linha, 50, arq);
      if (result)
     printf("Linha %d : %s\n",i,Linha);
      i++;
  }
    //Linha[0]= toupper(Linha[0]);
    //printf("%s",Linha);
    i=0;
    for (i=0; i<50;i++)
    {
      string[i]= toupper(Linha[i]);


    }

printf("%s",string);
fclose(arq);

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá. Está no caminho correto ao utilizar o fgets. Se for ler a documentação desta função verá que ela retorna null quando chega ao EOF ou nenhum carater é lido. E o que você quer fazer é ler linha a linha até chegar ao EOF. Por isso basta fazer um loop do género:

```
 while(fgets(Linha, 50, arq)) {
      printf("Linha %d : %s\n",i,Linha);
      i++; 
} 
//Enquanto o fgets não retornar null faz o que quiser com a linha lida para a variavel linha
```

Comment: entendi, muito obrigado.